# Inno Setup can run in "update mode"?

Tags: inno-setup

The situation is the following:
I have an first installer that correctly generates everything necessary for a first use of my product, this means that it creates the paths, registers the DLLs; font files (TTF); it deposits the corresponding EXE file and other normal installer stuff.

Besides, we have created a second installer to carry out the periodic update of the product, that is, to update "only" the EXE file with certain frequency.

Both installers perform version control of the mentioned executable file, in this way:

```
#define MyAppVersion GetVersionNumbersString(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "MyProg.exe")
; ---> And now, the above value is stored in these registry keys:
#define RegKey "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
#define RegKeyWOW6432="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
[Setup]
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
```

...and both installers share the key **GUID**:

```
[Setup]
AppId={{xxxxxxxxxxx}
```

But, when that second installer is run, it first does a complete uninstall of all pre-existing files (both the old EXE and the rest) and then installs its contents, leaving only the new EXE file in the destination.

How do I keep all the original files and only update the EXE file periodically?
Thanks for any idea. Best regards,

Comment: Inno Setup, as a default, doesn't uninstall anything when upgrading, so if your second package uninstalls things, it's because it contains `[UninstallDelete]` or other code that is explicitly uninstalling things. The fix would be "don't do that."

Comment: You are shipping main software and patches, so they cannot use the same `AppId`. If I were you, I will keep the main software unchanged, but let the patches share another `AppId`. And the patch installer should embed **more complicated logic** to locate the main software installation folder and replace the files wanted. There are more scenarios to consider, so don't expect it simple.

Comment: Inno Setup is not Delphi, unless you're working with Inno Setup's source code. I've removed the non-applicable tag. Please do not abuse the tag system by using tags that do not apply to your post. Doing so is a very good way to collect downvotes and get your question closed. Tags have meaning and relevance here.

Comment: Sorry, @KenBlanco.<br>That's right **Bill_Stewart**, I had included in the [Code] section an uninstall routine based on looking up "AppId" in the registry; Thank you very much **Lex_Li**, simply adding another "AppId" for uninstaller, that works fineit. Thank you all !!!